# How to randomly place turtles at each model opening?

Tags: netlogo

Every time that I open my Netlogo model, the created turtles are placed at the same place. I have 1000 simulations and I use the behaviorSpace. I tried `random-seed` but how can I use this function without writing, for each simulation in the behaviorSpace:

```
random-seed 0
create-turtles

random-seed 1
create-turtles  

random-seed 2
create-turtles  
....
random-seed 1000
create-turtles
```

?

**Update**

I don't use behaviorSpace to repeat simultaneously 1000 times my model but I open 1000 times my file .nlogo. I would like to find a way to have locations of turtles that are different at each file opening (I used `one-of` to place turtles in patches).

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(UPDATED)

In your comment, you supply the crucial information that you are using `import-world`. This restores the exact state of the entire world, *including* the state of the random number generator! As a result, you get the same model run every time afterwards.

If you want to re-seed the random number generator so you get a different run each time, then, after `import-world`, say `random-seed new-seed`.

Comment: Thank you very much Seth. I used `random-seed 0` to create my landscape. Then I exported my landscape. When I import it in Netlogo and I run my model, all turtles are always placed at the same place.Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
random-seed behaviorspace-run-number
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alan. I wrote `random-seed behaviorspace-run-number` in behaviorSpace. But It does't work. When I open my model and when I reopen my model, the turtles are always placed at the same place. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Your update changes the question substantially, as Seth notes.  However it also raises the question of why you are proceeding in this fashion.  Note that for replicability, you need to be able to reproduce exactly the state of your model on each run, including the state of the random number generator.